# Why does Haskell appear to default to reading Int when reading Num?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I didn't expect the following code to work:

```
foo :: (Num a) => a -> a
foo x = x + x

main = do
    print (foo (read "7"))
```

because it is not possible to fully infer the type of (read "7") based on the code. But GHC (6.12.3) thinks otherwise and prints 14.

If "7" is changed to "7.2", the code fails with "no parse". What's going on here? how is Haskell deciding which instance of Read to use?

Comment: `(Num a, Read a) => [Char] -> a` is clearly ambiguous. It has to decide somehow, so I guess `Int` happens to be the default for `Num`. Maybe because its the first instance of the typeclass somehow? I'm going to go manual searching. Its an interesting question.

Comment: Just for the record: it defaults to `Integer`, not `Int`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is caused by Haskell's [defaulting rules for the `Num` class](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4). If you added

```
default (Double, Integer)
```

to the top of your file, then you'd get the following results:

```
main = do
  print (foo (read "7")) -- prints "14.0"
  print (foo (read "7.2")) -- prints "14.2"
```

In a nutshell, defaulting rules are an attempt to "try to do the right thing" and save you from a compile error when you have an ambiguous type in your program. Unfortunately in this case it trades a compile-time error for a runtime error.

You can disable defaulting like so:

```
default ()
```

which will force you to explicitly disambiguate the types of such terms via type annotations:

```
print (foo (read "7" :: Int))
```

Answer (score 2):

Int is the default type in this instance. See sec. 6.3, Ambiguity and Type Defaulting, in A History of Haskell: Being Lazy with Class,

Comment: Noy `Int`, but `Integer` is the default.

Comment: Thanks for that reference. Here's the sentence that makes it clear why they'd include such an un-Haskell feature: "Performing numerical calculations on constants is one of the very first things a Haskell programmer does". So having ghci fail at 2+2 might put some people off.