# I don't understand number conversions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, sqrt

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime x = all (\y -> x `mod` y /= 0) [3, 5..floor(sqrt x)]
```

(I know I'm not checking for division by two--please ignore that.)
Here's what I get:

```
No instance for (Floating Int)
  arising from a use of `sqrt'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Int)
In the first argument of `floor', namely `(sqrt x)'
In the expression: floor (sqrt x)
In the second argument of `all', namely `[3, 5 .. floor (sqrt x)]'
```

I've spent literally hours trying everything I can think of to make this list using some variant of sqrt, including nonsense like

```
intSqrt :: Int -> Int
intSqrt x = floor (sqrt (x + 0.0))
```

It seems that (sqrt 500) works fine but (sqrt x) insists on x being a Floating (why?), and there is no function I can find to convert an Int to a real (why?).

I don't want a method to test primality, I want to understand how to fix this. Why is this so hard?

Comment: `sqrt 500` is valid because 500 is a valid literal for a floating point number. However `sqrt (500 :: Int)` would be invalid.

Comment: Why not just write what you are actually thinking of, which doesn't have anything to do with `Float`,`Double`, `floor`?:  `squares = map (\x -> x * x) [0 ..]` `squareRoot n = last $ takeWhile (<= n) squares`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unlike most other languages, Haskell distinguishes strictly between integral and floating-point types, and will not convert one to the other implicitly. See [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Converting_numbers) for how to do the conversion explicitly. There's even a `sqrt` example :-)

The underlying reason for this is that the combination of implicit conversions and Haskel's (rather complex but very cool) class system would make type reconstruction very difficult -- probably it would stretch it beyond the point where it can be done by machines at all. The language designers felt that getting type classes for arithmetic was worth the cost of having to specify conversions explicitly.

Comment: It's true that conversions play badly with the Haskell class system, but that's not the only reason to avoid conversions.  Many numeric conversions are lossy, so you really need to pay attention to what you are doing, e.g., `Double->Integer`, `Int->Float`.  Having them happen by magic is an invitation to subtle bugs.

Answer (score 19):

Your issue is that, although you've tried to fix it in a variety of ways, you haven't tried to do something `x`, which is exactly where your problem lies.  Let's look at the type of `sqrt`:

```
Prelude> :t sqrt
sqrt :: (Floating a) => a -> a
```

On the other hand, `x` is an `Int`, and if we ask GHCi for information about `Floating`, it tells us:

```
Prelude> :info Floating
class (Fractional a) => Floating a where
  pi :: a
  <...snip...>
  acosh :: a -> a
    -- Defined in GHC.Float
instance Floating Float -- Defined in GHC.Float
instance Floating Double -- Defined in GHC.Float
```

So the only types which are `Floating` are `Float`s and `Double`s.  We need a way to convert an `Int` to a `Double`, much as `floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b` goes the other direction.  Whenever you have a type question like this, you can ask [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), a Haskell search engine which searches types.  Unfortunately, if you search for [`Int -> Double`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=Int+-%3E+Double), you get lousy results.  But what if we relax what we're looking for?  If we search for [`Integer -> Double`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=Integer+-%3E+Double), we find that there's a function `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`, which is almost exactly what you want.  And if we relax our type all the way to [`(Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28Integral+a%2C+Num+b%29+%3D%3E+a+-%3E+b), you find that there is a function `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`.

Thus, to compute the square root of an integer, use `floor . sqrt $ fromIntegral x`, or use

```
isqrt :: Integral i => i -> i
isqrt = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral
```

You were thinking about the problem in the right direction for the output of `sqrt`; it returned a floating-point number, but you wanted an integer.  In Haskell, however, there's no notion of subtyping or implicit casts, so you need to alter the *input* to `sqrt` as well.

To address some of your other concerns:

> ```
> intSqrt :: Int -> Int
> intSqrt x = floor (sqrt (x + 0.0))
> ```

You call this "nonsense", so it's clear you don't expect it to work, but why doesn't it?  Well, the problem is that `(+)` has type `Num a => a -> a -> a`—you can only add two things of the same type.  This is generally good, since it means you can't add a complex number to a 5×5 real matrix; however, since `0.0` must be an instance of `Fractional`, you won't be able to add it to `x :: Int`.

> It seems that (sqrt 500) works fine…

This works because the type of `500` isn't what you expect.  Let's ask our trusty companion GHCi:

```
Prelude> :t 500
500 :: (Num t) => t
```

In fact, all integer literals have this type; they can be *any* sort of number, which works because the `Num` class contains the function `fromInteger :: Integer -> a`.  So when you wrote `sqrt 500`, GHC realized that `500` needed to satisfy `500 :: (Num t, Floating t) => t` (and it will implicitly pick `Double` for numeric types like that thank to the [defaulting rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165049/why-does-haskell-appear-to-default-to-reading-int-when-reading-num/6165123#6165123)).  Similarly, the `0.0` above has type `Fractional t => t`, thanks to `Fractional`'s `fromRational :: Rational -> a` function.

> … but (sqrt x) insists on x being a Floating …

See above, where we look at the type of `sqrt`.

> … and there is no function I can find to convert an Int to a real ….

Well, you have one now: `fromIntegral`.  I don't know why you couldn't find it; apparently Hoogle gives much worse results than I was expecting, thanks to the generic type of the function.

> Why is this so hard?

I hope it isn't anymore, now that you have `fromIntegral`.

Comment: Do you know why `Rational` is not an instance of any classes but the haskell wiki implies that it's part of the Fractional typeclass?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: I can't reproduce that myself; you might be finding that `:i Rational` doesn't display any instances, but that's because it's a type synonym, and it's the `Ratio` type that has instances.  If that doesn't answer your question, please, ask a new one with details and I'm sure you'll get an answer! :-)

Comment: Yea I found it after looking at Data.Ratio module. I found it funny trying to convert a ratio to a fraction. Is it possible to make `2 % 3` into `2/5` or `3/5`? Perhaps something like leftFraction, rightFraction?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: Your questions aren't really well-suited to comments :-)  Again, if you're having trouble, ask a new question – or you can always use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) first to search for functions by type!